# Solve this interview puzzle

Tags: lateral-thinking

This is a simple interview puzzle.

> Mira's mother is Bhavana. Then Bhavana is the ________of Mira's
>   mother.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer is

> name

Because

> Mira's mother is Bhavana. Then Bhavana is the name of Mira's mother.

Comment: Correct!! This question is IAS question.

Answer (score 2):

The correct answer to this simple question is

> **name.** 
>  This question tries to trick the interviewee into thinking about a relationship as the answer, as the first sentence mentions a relationship.

Answer (score 1):

> **name**. Mira's mother is Bhavana. Then Bhavana is the **name** of Mira's mother.

Answer (score 0):

> name. Then Bhavana is the name of Mira's mother.